# How can I access port 80 of another container, when port 80 is already exposed?

Tags: docker, networking

I have a docker file that runs some integration tests between two containers. It looks a bit like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
    test_client:
        image: client:latest
        depends_on:
          - test_server
        command: bash -c "run_test.sh -p 80"
    test_server:
        image: server:latest
```

`test_server` launches a web server on port 80, but that same port is already exposed within `test_client` (I don't have control over the part of the `client:latest` image where the port is exposed. I tried using the `port: 8080:80` to forward port 80 to 8080 in the server, but that only changes the port exposed on the host, not within the docker environment.

How can I connect `test_client` to `test_server` in such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a proxy to forward traffic between the two services, I typically do something like this which includes automated SSL with certbot. In the example below I have two services listening on port 80/443 (Sonarqube and Jenkins). You can also see I can reference container hosts by name (https://jenkins:8080)

```
nginx:
container_name: nginx-certbot
restart: unless-stopped
image: staticfloat/nginx-certbot
networks:
  - local
ports:
  - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
  - "0.0.0.0:443:443"
environment:
  CERTBOT_EMAIL: <insert_email>
volumes:
  - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/user.conf.d:ro
  - letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

And this is what my nginx config looks like

```
server {
listen              443 ssl;
server_name jenkins.hauntedmansion.io;
ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.hauntedmansion.io/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jenkins.hauntedmansion.io/privkey.pem;

client_max_body_size 20M;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass         http://jenkins:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_redirect     http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://jenkins.hauntedmansion.io;
  }
}
```

If you want to see the full docker compose example check it out here:

https://gist.github.com/cvega/66e0e5a2815e9b923da2c616f74dea7e